# How to extract information on class and properties of a owl file using rowlex?

Tags: rowlex

I am new to rowlex and would like to know how it works. I understood that it converts owl to a dll file. But i am unaware as to how to read from it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one way of using ROWLEX is by generating .NET assemblies from your OWL files. In the dll-s you will find C# classes equivalent to your OWL classes. If you would like to see them, you can inspect them by the well-known [Reflector tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) (which was free software till February 28, 2011), just like any other non-obfuscated .NET assemblies.

With the generated assembly, you can create or browse RDF documents that comply to your ontology. Here is an example [how to create and RDF document](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/Content/CreatingRdf.htm) complying to the [zoo ontology](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/Content/testOntology.owl.xml).
And here is an example [how to browse the content of an RDF document](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/Content/BrowsingRDF.htm) that contains individuals complying to the [zoo ontology](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/Content/testOntology.owl.xml).

For each ontology class, ROWLEX generates two .NET classes: a light class and a full class. Mostly light classes are more than enough, but if you want to understand the difference, read the second half of [this page](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/Content/AssemblyGeneration.htm).

Further details on usage, you can find [here](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/HowToUse.aspx).